# How to use locally available package/module while building python package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, setup.py

I am working on a system that does not support numpy when installed from pip. Because our system has a different CPU arch, we had to port the package for our system. Hence, if we do `pip install numpy` it will fail on our system.

The problem is I cannot build any package that depends on numpy, because setup.py will try to install numpy from the pip and fails. Note: We have a ported version of numpy available to us locally.

I would like to know how can I use locally available packages when installing any package.

At present, I clone the package that I like to port, then I run `pip install --target=mypath .`. Is there any arg that I can supply so that pip does not try to install it from the repo and use the local one?

Comment: I never tried it, but perhaps you can place your modified `numpy` package inside `pip`'s cache dir (or use `--cache-dir <dir>` arg with the dir of your custom package). This way `pip` should use your modified version.